# Database relations, foreign key and diagram - MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, diagram

I trying to make database diagram with MySQL workbench. Something like this :

```
users
--FK user_logins
--FK user_tabs
----FK tab_favorites
--FK user_settings
...
```

But when I make some relations in diagram, MySQL Workbench makes additional column for each table as foreign key. So if I have 20 tables related to `users` table, it will make 20 additional cols in `users` table.

I am n00b in DBs, but this looks bad. Is better to make `users.user_id` FK to all other tables? And if is, how to make it with MySQL workbench diagram tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are defining the relation the wrong way around.

I take it that a `user` may be related to several (e.g.) `logins`, so the foreign key column must be in the `login` table.

Please note, the term "foreign key" is the name of the column that *references* a foreign table (formally, the *referenced* column must be the primary key). So for instance:

```
        User         Login
        -------      -------
        id (PK)      id (PK)
        name         login
        ...          user_id (FK to user.id)     <== this is the foreign key
        -------      ...
                     -------
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to re-use existing columns use the last toolbutton for creating an 1:n relationship. Then pick the source and target columns as you need.

[image]